# Why eclipse is not responding after (Ctrl+shift+r)?

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, xhtml, ide-customization

I have a problem with my eclipse.. every time when I try to open .xhtml file using open resource shortcut(Ctrl+Shift+R) my eclipse is going to not responding mode(every thing was grayed out). It is working to open the .java files though.

It worked before with .xhtml files also.
 please help me out.

error logs

```
eclipse.buildId=4.3.2.M20140221-1700
java.version=1.6.0_38
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

Error
Wed Oct 01 10:33:55 EDT 2014
A workspace crash was detected. The previous session did not exit normally. Not using saved taglib indexes.
```

and

```
eclipse.buildId=4.3.2.M20140221-1700
java.version=1.6.0_38
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

Error
Wed Oct 01 10:36:02 EDT 2014
Loading web root taglibs for project: Project_Name

java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Project_Name\WebContent\WEB-INF\facelets\taglib\facelet-taglib_1_0.dtd (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.FileURIHandlerImpl.createInputStream(FileURIHandlerImpl.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ExtensibleURIConverterImpl.createInputStream(ExtensibleURIConverterImpl.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLHandler.resolveEntity(XMLHandler.java:817)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.EntityResolverWrapper.resolveEntity(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.resolveEntityAsPerStax(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLLoadImpl.load(XMLLoadImpl.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLResourceImpl.doLoad(XMLResourceImpl.java:253)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceImpl.load(ResourceImpl.java:1518)
    at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.facelet.core.internal.registry.taglib.TagModelLoader.loadFromInputStream(TagModelLoader.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.facelet.core.internal.registry.taglib.ContextParamSpecifiedFaceletTaglibLocator.createTagRecord(ContextParamSpecifiedFaceletTaglibLocator.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.facelet.core.internal.registry.taglib.ContextParamSpecifiedFaceletTaglibLocator.doLocate(ContextParamSpecifiedFaceletTaglibLocator.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.facelet.core.internal.registry.taglib.AbstractFaceletTaglibLocator.doLocate(AbstractFaceletTaglibLocator.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.common.internal.locator.AbstractLocator.locate(AbstractLocator.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.facelet.core.internal.registry.taglib.ProjectTaglibDescriptor$1.run(ProjectTaglibDescriptor.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.facelet.core.internal.registry.taglib.ProjectTaglibDescriptor.initialize(ProjectTaglibDescriptor.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.facelet.core.internal.registry.taglib.ProjectTaglibDescriptor.getTagLibraries(ProjectTaglibDescriptor.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.facelet.core.internal.registry.FaceletTagRegistry.initialize(FaceletTagRegistry.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.facelet.core.internal.registry.FaceletTagRegistry.getAllTagLibraries(FaceletTagRegistry.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.facelet.core.internal.registry.FaceletTagRegistry.getTagLibrary(FaceletTagRegistry.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.facelet.core.internal.metadata.FaceletNamespaceMetaDataLocator.locateMetaDataModelProviders(FaceletNamespaceMetaDataLocator.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.common.metadata.internal.DomainLoadingStrategy.locateMetaDataSourceInstances(DomainLoadingStrategy.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.common.metadata.internal.DomainLoadingStrategy.load(DomainLoadingStrategy.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.common.metadata.internal.MetaDataModel.load(MetaDataModel.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.common.metadata.internal.MetaDataModelManager.loadMetadata(MetaDataModelManager.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.common.metadata.internal.MetaDataModelManager.getModel(MetaDataModelManager.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.common.metadata.query.internal.MetaDataQueryHelper.getMDModel(MetaDataQueryHelper.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.common.metadata.query.internal.MetaDataQueryHelper.getModel(MetaDataQueryHelper.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.common.metadata.query.internal.taglib.TaglibDomainMetaDataQuery.findTagLibraryModel(TaglibDomainMetaDataQuery.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.jst.pagedesigner.editors.palette.impl.PaletteHelper.getOrCreateTaglibPaletteDrawer(PaletteHelper.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.jst.pagedesigner.editors.palette.impl.PaletteItemManager.registerHTMLCategory(PaletteItemManager.java:349)
    at org.eclipse.jst.pagedesigner.editors.palette.impl.PaletteItemManager.initTagRegistry(PaletteItemManager.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.jst.pagedesigner.editors.palette.impl.PaletteItemManager.init(PaletteItemManager.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.jst.pagedesigner.editors.palette.impl.PaletteItemManager.getInstance(PaletteItemManager.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jst.pagedesigner.editors.palette.DesignerPaletteRoot.<init>(DesignerPaletteRoot.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.jst.pagedesigner.editors.palette.DesignerPaletteRootFactory.createPaletteRoot(DesignerPaletteRootFactory.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.jst.pagedesigner.editors.SimpleGraphicalEditor.getPaletteRoot(SimpleGraphicalEditor.java:513)
    at org.eclipse.gef.ui.parts.GraphicalEditorWithFlyoutPalette.setEditDomain(GraphicalEditorWithFlyoutPalette.java:145)
    at org.eclipse.jst.pagedesigner.editors.SimpleGraphicalEditor.<init>(SimpleGraphicalEditor.java:166)
    at org.eclipse.jst.pagedesigner.editors.HTMLEditor.sash_createAndAddDesignSourcePage(HTMLEditor.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.jst.pagedesigner.editors.HTMLEditor.createPages(HTMLEditor.java:453)
    at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.createPartControl(MultiPageEditorPart.java:358)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.createPartControl(CompatibilityPart.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityEditor.createPartControl(CompatibilityEditor.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.create(CompatibilityPart.java:323)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:877)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:857)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer.createWidget(ContributedPartRenderer.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:949)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:633)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:735)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:706)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:700)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:685)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl$1.handleEvent(PartServiceImpl.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler$1.run(UIEventHandler.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4688)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application$1.syncExec(E4Application.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.handleEvent(UIEventHandler.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerWrapper.handleEvent(EventHandlerWrapper.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.dispatchEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.sendEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent.sendEvent(EventComponent.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.send(EventBroker.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.UIEventPublisher.notifyChanged(UIEventPublisher.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.BasicNotifierImpl.eNotify(BasicNotifierImpl.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.impl.ElementContainerImpl.setSelectedElement(ElementContainerImpl.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.showElementInWindow(ModelServiceImpl.java:576)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.bringToTop(ModelServiceImpl.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.delegateBringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:619)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.bringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.showPart(PartServiceImpl.java:1046)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3112)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$21(WorkbenchPage.java:3034)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$8.run(WorkbenchPage.java:3016)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3012)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2976)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2967)
    at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:534)
    at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:493)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.EditorUtility.openInEditor(EditorUtility.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.EditorUtility.openInEditor(EditorUtility.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.OpenAction.run(OpenAction.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.OpenAction.run(OpenAction.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.SelectionDispatchAction.dispatchRun(SelectionDispatchAction.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.SelectionDispatchAction.run(SelectionDispatchAction.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.navigator.OpenAndExpand.run(OpenAndExpand.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.RetargetAction.run(RetargetAction.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.CommonNavigatorManager$3.open(CommonNavigatorManager.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.ui.OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper$InternalListener.open(OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$2.run(StructuredViewer.java:866)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.fireOpen(StructuredViewer.java:864)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1152)
    at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.CommonViewer.handleOpen(CommonViewer.java:462)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$6.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1256)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireOpenEvent(OpenStrategy.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$2(OpenStrategy.java:269)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(OpenStrategy.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1057)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4170)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3759)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:997)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:611)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
```

Thanks

Comment: Check the error log. Also which OS?

Comment: I am using eclipse on Windows 7

Comment: "Every thing grayed out" means Eclipse hangs (doesn't respond anymore when Windows sends events). Try to wait for a few minutes and check the error log. http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-error_log_view.htm

Comment: Thanks for the link.. I found following error eclipse.buildId=4.3.2.M20140221-1700
java.version=1.6.0_38
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

Error
Wed Oct 01 10:33:55 EDT 2014
A workspace crash was detected. The previous session did not exit normally. Not using saved taglib indexes.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the error in a code block (paste the error, select the text and click on `{}`).

Comment: I just edited the question.. sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first error means that Eclipse has crashed. This can leave the workspace in a corrupt state. If nothing else works, try to create a new workspace or [use these instructions to clean it](http://blog.pdark.de/2011/09/02/restoring-a-corrupted-workspace-in-eclipse/).

The second error means that you refer to `facelet-taglib_1_0.dtd` in one of your files and Eclipse can't find it. Try to add the file to your project. Eclipse might hang here because it tries to download the file from the Internet and that doesn't work for some reason (firewall, missing proxy server, etc).